# What would someone's unofficial support of another be called?

Tags: single-word-requests

For the sake of this question, I'm going to use the US 2016 presidential election as an example.

Let's say that Trump and his campaign has no official or even non-official collusion with Putin or Russia. He has no ties with them whatsoever. However, Putin supports his campaign from behind the scenes and directly influence the election to Trump's benefit.

Now, if Trump is well aware of Putin's support and have made deals with him, he can be called a puppet of Putin. If he was brainwashed, he can even be called a Manchurian Candidate.

If he has no knowledge and no deals with Putin, yet the latter still supports him directly, what does that make him?  What is the relationship called?

Comment: Your question title and body don't match. You are asking "What do you call **unofficial support** in the title and "What does that make Trump? What is **the relationship** called?" Please edit your question with an example sentence where the word would be used. Otherwise, your question is unclear. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).  The answers below prove it is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Unwitting beneficiary, unwitting conspirator, unwitting partner.

[Unwitting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unwitting) (definition 2)

> not knowing; unaware; ignorant; oblivious; unconscious:

Comment: To me, *unwitting* denotes a feeling of the person involved not knowing. An *unwitting participant* in a crime is someone who does not know that they are participating in a crime. However, in the OP's case, Putin is aware that he is giving support, he is just not on the record as doing so.

Comment: But Trump is unaware.  The question is about Trump's portion of the relationship.  Putin's portion of the relationship would be described as *covert*.

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, answering the question posed in the title, I think Putin could be called the *silent benefactor*, *anonymous donor* or *secret admirer*.

Perhaps we could call Trump the *unknowing beneficiary* or *natural ally*.

Comment: I like all of those but especially, and I mean this without political bias, secret admirer. Secret admirers are usually so tame so I love this application

Comment: I see Putin as a crypto-Trump supporter.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's scenario, where Trump has no idea of Putin's crypto-support behind the scenes, I think that this might be a case for saying that Trump is Putin's **dupe** or, put another way, the **dupe of Putin**.

**Dupe:** (*noun*) A person who is easily deceived or is used to carry out the designs of another (Free Dictionary).